# PHP/MySQL lock page and client crash

Tags: php, mysql, crash, deadlock, onunload

I have a simple PHP/MySQL website. There is one page inside which should only by accessed by one user at a time:

- If one user visits this page and nobody else is on it, the page is displayed;
- If one user visits this page and someone else is already seeing it, the page is considered "locked" and the user is directed to another page.

To keep track of who is visiting this page or not, I have a MYSQL table with the following structure:

```
________________________________________
| ID | ID_User | Visit_TS              |
|____|_________|_______________________|
| 1  |    20   | 2015-01-12 10:00:01   |
|____|_________|_______________________|
```

In this case, the page is currently being visited by user ID 20. If any other user tries to visit it, they can't since user 20 is locking it.

If user (with the ID 20)

- Visits another page or
- Closes the browser (ajax on window unload)

Then the table is reset.

However, **if the user's client machine crashes**, or if they do a brute shutdown, the lock is never released (In this case, the user did not visit another page, and the window was not unloaded...)

In this case I have a deadlock.

Theoretically, we have to wait until the user goes back online and visits another page or closes the browser - but this is no way to solve the issue.

How could I tackle this problem?

Should I create an automatic PHP script which periodically resets the table?

Comment: you can use something like ajax to check the user is still available, say every 10 seconds

Comment: Right now, I am trying something like http://ajaxpatterns.org/Heartbeat

Comment: why you want such function?

Comment: I'm currently studying several alternatives... With the Heartbeat, the application will have the client send regular pings (through ajax or something similar) to the server. If the client stops sending a ping, it's likely because he has terminated session or crashed